# Flutter REST API save file to phone

Tags: flutter, rest

I can save the file from the API to the computer by "save and download" in postman

[postman - send and download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rpa12.png)

[postman - only send](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8HAP.png)

How can I do this on the phone with flutter?

[this is my http request code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhjUH.png)

Answer (score 1):

Using dio you can call the `download()` method instead of `get()`.